# SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost) (severity 9)

Tags: pdo, sap-ase, zend-framework3, php-7.0

**SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost) (severity 9)**

I'm connecting Sybase15.7 using php7.0n getting above error.
Please help me resolving this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the port from hostname and adding it to .conf.

```
[192.168.5.57]
    host = 0.0.0.0
    port = 1433
```